# cannot use DISTINCT with WITHIN GROUP in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I am trying to make below query compatible with Postgres, which is originally written for Oracle

```
select concat(s.udise_sch_code ,tch.teacher_id) comp_id,
        s.sch_id as sch_id, 
        s.udise_sch_code as sch_code,
        s.school_name as school_name,
        v.latitude as latitude,
        v.longitude as longitude,
        tch.teacher_id as tch_id, 
        tch.name as tch_name,
        tch.social_category as social_cat,
        to_char(tch.startdate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm') as startdate,
        **LISTAGG(DISTINCT phone_no, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY phone_no) AS phone_no,**
        v.village_id as village_id,
        v.village_name as village_name,
        v.sch_id as vsch_id,
        LISTAGG(DISTINCT (r.rolerosterid||','||to_char(r.rolerosterstartdate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm')||',' ||to_char(r.rolerosterenddate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm')), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.rolerosterid) combinedrosterentry
    from school s 
    LEFT JOIN teacher tch on s.sch_id = tch.sch_id
    LEFT JOIN village v on s.sch_id = v.sch_id
    LEFT JOIN contact c on tch.teacher_id = c.teacher_ids
    LEFT JOIN rosterentry r on tch.teacher_id = r.teacher_ids 
    group by c.teacher_ids,concat(s.udise_sch_code ,tch.teacher_id), s.sch_id, s.udise_sch_code, s.school_name, v.latitude, 
    v.longitude, tch.teacher_id, tch.name, tch.social_category, to_char(tch.startdate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm'), 
    v.village_id, v.village_name, v.sch_id
```

I am getting below error

```
ERROR:  cannot use DISTINCT with WITHIN GROUP
LINE 11:         LISTAGG(DISTINCT phone_no, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER ...
```

It looks like DISTINCT is not supported with WITHIN GROUP.
I would be needing help to understand and resolve this issue, in order to make it work for Postgres (version 13)

Comment: `listagg` isn't supported in Postgres, you need to use `string_agg()`

Comment: Even if string_agg() is used, getting same error "cannot use DISTINCT with WITHIN GROUP"

Comment: So, what does it do?